# use Boolean value from Firestore in if-statement

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, boolean

When a new user creates an account they will be added to the Cloud Firestore as such -->
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA8pZ.png), the document name is the UserId provided by Firebase Authentication. I would like to use the "authenticated" Boolean value in a if statement but I can't figure out how to do that. Any help is greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: What have you tried so far and what issues did you encounter?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Could you please provide some code also response to the previous questions.